# Intent Crashing my Application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am currently sending a variable once the user logs in through an intent and receiving it with Bundle.

I have checked the LogCat and I receive the variable but once I receive it the application crashes....Below is my Code.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int cameraId = 0;
    final TextView welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelcomeText);
    final TextView relocationId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RelocationID);
    final TextView addressOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressOne);
    final TextView addressTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressTwo);
    final String RelocationId = bundle.getString("UID");
    relocationId.setText("Your Relocation: #" + RelocationId);
```

This is what My bundle looks like on the receiving end (but crashes after). If I comment out the last two lines it continues like normal.

LogCat:

```
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testingapp/com.testingapp.MoveContactsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at com.testingapp.MoveContactsActivity.onCreate(MoveContactsActivity.java:69)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-25 18:35:50.749: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    ... 11 more
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: While you are retrieving the logcat, make sure that the `TextView` `relocationId` is not `null`

Comment: @codeMagic The LogCat shows Null on that Value...How come it is showing like that....Also updated with logCat

Comment: I have posted an answer that should clear it up. If not then please post the 'onCreate()` and xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the `TextView` doesn't exist in the `Layout` that you have inflated. Check your xml that you have spelled the name correctly. If you still can't fix the error then post where you inflate the `Layout` probably in the `onCreate()` and the xml. Since your `TextView` is `null` you get a `NPE` when you try to call `setText()` on it

Comment: LowerCase r On the ID call to RelocationId

Comment: It's always the little things that get you :) Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have actually added extras previously? From the documentation

```
Returns the map of all extras previously added with putExtra(), 
or null if none have been added.
```

I suspect that the getExtras() method is returning null, because no extras have been added to the intent before you are calling it.

Are you running the new activity directly, or are you starting this activity using an intent (with extras set).

Or as others have mentioned, it might be your textview that is the problem. A really easy way of testing this would be just commenting out the last  like. If this fixes the problem, its your textview that the issue.

Comment: String UserId = RelocationId;
      Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
        MoveContactsActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("UID1", UserId);
      startActivity(intent);

Comment: that is my extra calling and transfer of the variable through the intent.

Comment: UID1? is that a type-o? otherwise, thats your issue right there

Comment: Type-o, turned out that it was because like codeMagic said the TextView was returning null....I used a Capital R instead of r for the ID call of RelocationID.